# Auto Add Single quotes where needed to php code

Tags: php, addition, quotes

i have a php class that i made long time ago , but the issue that i made all methods , etc ..

without quotes , so therefor i made a small script that automatically dos that .

```
echo "<form action='?do=go' method='post'>
<textarea cols='70' rows='20' name='text' ></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='        Go        ' >
</form>";


if(isset($_GET['do']) == 'go'){


 $test = $_POST['text'];
 foreach($list as $val ){

 $test = str_replace("[$val]", "['$val']",$test);

 }  

  echo "<textarea cols='70' rows='20' name='text2' >$test</textarea>";  




}
```

$list contain all database fields as an array : eg.

```
$list = array('fieldname1',
'fieldname2','fieldname3');
```

so result :

```
$id = $r['user_id'];
$fname = $r['user_fname'];
```

**The ISSUE ::**

everything gets replaced even if it is in **query** or **echo** :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE fname SET fname=$newfname where user_id='$r['user_id']'");
```

and

```
echo 'my name is $r['fname']';
```

**does anyone know how to overcome this issue ??**

one more thing that i need to replace/check everything in get,post,request to be in this form  :: **$_POST['fname'];** insted of **$_POST[fname];**

thanx in advance..

Comment: You cannot do that with a simple search and replace, it does need manual post-editing. Better yet use an IDE/editor with a regex search-and-replace stepping through each instance. An actual solution would involve the PHP tokenizer, but isn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a \ before the '   ??

That should do the trick if you want to keep your single quote.

Comment: You could try doing an ajax call and sending values to another PHP page where you would then process them, giving you solid strings for dynamic values instead of $_POST.

Comment: i am NOt going to change methods of more than 40 pages .. all i want is as i asked errore , just error correction.